отправка первого коментария под пост aiogram3?
Пишу для себя тг бота, написал код отправки сообщения под пост на канал(вроде как), а бот отправляет сообщение прямо в канале, а в комментариях тишина
@test.channel_post()
async def channel_message_in_group(message: Message):
    await message.reply('смс от канала')


Ну дак правильно. Комментарии в тг - это группа с другим id. Нужно добавить бота в эту группу и при появлении поста, отправлять комментарий как ответ на пост. И тогда сообщение появится в комментариях, а не просто сообщение в группе
